# Scope to fetch users with different roles on Mongoid (undefined method `to_criteria' for #<Array>)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I am trying to define a scope in my User model on Mongoid to fetch users with either **manager** or **supervisor** role.

In order to implement roles functionality I have used **rolify** gem (https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify).

As per official gem documentation (https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify#class-level) I am using **with_any_role** method as follows:

```
scope :managers_and_supervisors, -> { with_any_role(:manager, :supervisor) }
```

but when tried using the same scope in rails console I am getting **undefined method `to_criteria' for Array** error as follows:

```
1.9.3-p551 :001 > User.managers_and_supervisors
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_criteria' for #<Array:0x0000000e9c3d40>
```

but if I directly try to invoke the **with_any_role** method in rails console as follows:

```
1.9.3-p551 :002 > User.with_any_role(:manager, :supervisor)
```

it works fine.

I need some suggestions to correct my scope definition to fetch users with either **manager** or **supervisor** role.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your version of ruby. From your console output it looks like you're runnning 1.9.3. From their github:

```
Requirements
Rails >= 4.2
ActiveRecord >= 4.2 or Mongoid >= 4.0
supports ruby 2.2+, JRuby 1.6.0+ (in 1.9 mode) and Rubinius 2.0.0dev (in 1.9 mode)
```

You may well need to upgrade Rails too if you're using Rails ~ 3

Comment: upgrading my Ruby and Rails version might help, but frankly speaking the scope should work in my current versions of Ruby (1.9.3-p551) & Rails (3.2.8) because I have already defined similar types of scopes as follows:

`scope :managers, -> { with_role(:manager) }`

**&**

`scope :supervisor, -> { with_role(:supervisor) }`

and they work perfectly fine.

Comment: Sure but it looks like the issue arises when you include more than one argument into the with_role method. If that's how they state you should include more than one argument, and only using 1 argument causes a ruby error, I think that points to the ruby version.